# Weird text displayed after using netcat to connect with remote server

Tags: command-line, 18.04, netcat

This question might be stupid but I have a small problem which I can't resolve.
I used netcat to connect to a CTF server and while connecting, I had opened many Ubuntu windows. This is when a line of text started appearing on my terminal every time I type a command 
[Text keeps showing up on my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yv0gC.png)
Why did this happen? I have killed the connection but this keeps showing up. I used ps -aux to look for unknown processes on my Ubuntu but nothing suspicious showed up 
[Result from ps -aux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFqgh.png)
Is there any possible reason for this ? I'm new to Ubuntu so I might have screwed up something, but I can't figure out what's wrong :((
[Output of echo $PS1 $PS2 $PS3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ic9aQ.png)

Comment: Can you open a new terminal and see if it happens there too? Also, what is the output of `echo $PS1 $PS2 $PS3`

Comment: It still happens in new terminals. I have tried closing and opening new ones but it didn't work. Also, I added the output of `echo $PS1 $PS2 $PS3` in my post

Comment: It might not be even close to the real problem, but someone might find my comment useful. Once I've bought a cooling pad for my laptop. Every time I did connect it, an url or string has been typed automatically into focused window. Throwing this piece of garbage into electro-junk helped. :) Keep an eye on your equipment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your computer was compromised. Read all about it [here (last year's but valid)](https://insomnihack.ch/2019-teaser-results/). At the end it tells you how to get rid of the message.

Comment: Thank you. It solved my problem :))